# Building a Java Vector from Scratch

Tags: java, arrays, vector, jvm

Long story short, I am in a university Comp Sci class, and the Professor wants us to build a Vector but from scratch. Are their any good tutorials on the web for something like this? I did a Google search but nothing really came up.

EDIT

According to the document the teacher gave out the vector needs to be able to do the following:

- append(Object element) – appending the element at the end of the vector
- clear() – make the vector collection empty
- contains(Object element) – check whether the vector contains the element
- elementAt(int index) – access the element at the given index
- indexOf(Object element) – find the index of the element
- insertAt(int index, Object element) – insert the element at the given index
- isEmpty() – check whether the vector is empty
- removeAt(int index) – remove the element at the given index
- remove(Object element) – remove the element from the vector
- replace(int index, Object element) – replace the element at the given index with the given element
- size() – get the number of elements in the current vector
- ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) – make sure the vector gets at least the given capacity
- clone() – returns a cloned copy of this vector
- removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) – removes from this vector all of the elements whose index is between fromIndex, inclusive and toIndex, exclusive
- toString() – returns a string representation of this vector, containing the String representation of each element
- reverse() – reverse the elements in this vector
- merge(MyVector vector2) – add all the elements in vector2 to the end of this vector

Additionally the class needs to implment Cloneable and be self expanding.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
package collection;

public class MyVector implements Cloneable {

    protected Object[] items;
    protected int arraySize;
    protected int maxCap;

    public MyVector (int initialCapacity) {
        super();
        if (initialCapacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);
        }
        this.items = new Object[initialCapacity];
        this.arraySize = 0;
        this.maxCap = initialCapacity;
    }

    public MyVector() {
        this(10);
    }

    public void append(Object element) {
        int newArraySize = this.arraySize + 1;
        if(this.maxCap == newArraySize) {
            this.items = this.increaseCap(newArraySize);
            this.items[this.arraySize] = element;
            this.arraySize += 1;
            //System.out.println(this.items[this.arraySize);
        } else {
            this.items[this.arraySize] = element;
            this.arraySize +=1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "[";
        //output = this.items[0].toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
            output += this.items[i] + ", ";
        }
        output += "]";
        return output;
    }
    public void clear() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
            this.items[i] = null;
            this.arraySize = 0;
        }
    }
    public boolean contains(Object element) {
        boolean doesContain = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
            if(element == this.items[i]) {
                doesContain = true;
                i = this.arraySize;
            }
        }
        return doesContain;
    }
    public Object elementAt(int index) {
        if(this.arraySize >= index) {
            return this.items[index];
        } else {
            Object temp = null;
            System.out.println("No index of " + index);
            return temp; 
        }
    }
    public Object indexOf(Object element) {
        Object index = "No value found";
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
            if(element == this.items[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;        
            } 
        }
        return index;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(this.arraySize == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void replace(int index, Object element) {
        if(this.arraySize > index) {
            this.items[index] = element;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No element at " + index);
        }
    }
    public int size() {
        return this.arraySize;
    }
    public void reverse() {
        Object[] temp = new Object[this.items.length];
        int j = this.arraySize;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
            temp[j] = this.items[i];
            j--;
        }
        this.items = temp;
    }
    public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
        if(minCapacity > this.items.length) {
            this.items = this.increaseCap(minCapacity);
        }
    }
    public Object[] increaseCap(int minCap) {
        Object[] arr1 = new Object[minCap * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < minCap; i++) {
            arr1[i] = this.items[i];
        }
        this.maxCap = this.maxCap * 2;
        return arr1;
    }
    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        return this.items;
    }
    public boolean checkIndex(int index) {
        boolean check = false;
        if(index < this.arraySize) {
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }
    public void removeAt(int index) {
        if(true == this.checkIndex(index)) {
            Object[] temp = new Object[this.arraySize - 1];
            for(int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
                temp[j] = this.items[j];
            }
            for(int j = index + 1; j < this.arraySize; j++) {
                temp[j-1] = this.items[j];
            }
            this.items = temp;
            this.arraySize = this.arraySize - 1;
        }
    }
    public void insertAt(int index, Object element) {
        if (this.checkIndex(index) == true) {
            Object[] temp = new Object[this.arraySize];
            for(int i = index; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
                temp[i+1] = this.items[i];
            }
            this.items[index] = element;
            for (int i = index + 1; i < this.arraySize; i++) {
                this.items[i] = temp[i - 1];
            }
            this.arraySize = this.arraySize - 1;
        }
    }
    public void remove(Object element) {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if(this.items[i] == element) {
                this.removeAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        for(int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
            this.removeAt(i);
        }
    }
    public void merge(MyVector vector2) {
        this.ensureCapacity(vector2.size() + this.arraySize);
        for(int i = 0; i < vector2.size(); i++) {
            this.append(vector2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to us what you know what a vector is?

Comment: My suggestion would be to think it out. What is the interface it needs to support? What are the performance characteristics it needs to achieve. Etc.

Comment: You don't need a tutorial. You need to do the work. Step 1: design the API; step 2: design the internals; step 3: code away.

Comment: Or if all else fails, copy the implementation in the JDK which you already have downloaded.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - That assumes that the Professor's definition of `Vector` has something to do with the JDK's version.

Comment: @TedHopp Without more information, I agree, there is no way to know.

Comment: @TedHopp Many new to Java developers who use Vector come from using `std::vector` in C++ without realising it is very different in many ways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants us the mimic Java's Vector ADT.His exact words were: "1. Implement the vector ADT as MyVector class (implements Cloneable) with the following public methods: (etc) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your assignment is replicating `java.util.Vector`, I would look at what a [Vector](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_vector_class.htm) is in order to replicate it:

> **Vector** implements a ***dynamic array***. It is similar to **ArrayList**, but
>   with two differences:
>
> 1. Vector is ***synchronized***.
> 2. Vector contains many ***legacy methods*** that are not part of the collections framework.

You *could* attempt to use an ArrayList in a synchronous manner in order to replicate a Vector, but I'm sure there are much better solutions.

Comment: You're assuming that the term "Vector" used in the assignment is the same as `java.util.Vector`. For all we know, the "Vector" of the assignment is a 3D geometric object that needs to support cross product, magnitude, etc.

Comment: @TedHoppp Good point.  Let me update answer.